# Discord.py- Economy system

Tags: python, json, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)

  user = ctx.author

  users = await get_bank_data()
  
  wallet_amt= users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]
  bank_amt= users[str(user.id)]["Bank"]


  em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance.", color=discord.Color.teal()) 
  em.add_field(
    name="Wallet Balance",value=wallet_amt
  )
  em.add_field(
    name="Bank Balance",value=bank_amt
  )
  await ctx.send(embed=em)

async def open_account(user):
  users = await get_bank_data()
  
  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0
  
  with open("bank.json",'w') as f:
    users = json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_bank_data():
  with open("bank.json",'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)
  return users

@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)

  user = ctx.author


  users = await get_bank_data()

  earnings = random.randrange(101)
  await ctx.send(f"Someone gave your {earnings} coins")

  users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings

  with open("bank.json",'r') as f:
    users = json.dump(users,f)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So I was making an economy system for my discord bot, and faced this error. I dont really know how to fix this, and doing stuff only leads to more errors. It would be cool if someone could correct, and probably explain where i went wrong.

Comment: Have you created the JSON file correctly? It should look like this: `{}`

Comment: yep i have made the file correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided code makes no sense at all in some places, for example:

```py
users = json.dump(users,f)
```

`users` has no further use and no effect on the code.

Furthermore, your `beg` command contains a logical error. You try to read a JSON (`r`) and `dump` at the same time, then you get the error that you cannot write to the JSON file.

**To get around all this we come to the following code:**

```py
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0

    with open("bank.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open("bank.json", 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users

@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance.", color=discord.Color.teal())
    em.add_field(name="Wallet Balance", value=wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name="Bank Balance", value=bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_bank_data()

    earnings = random.randrange(101)

    await ctx.send(f"Someone gave your {earnings} coins")

    users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings

    with open("bank.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

its just
{
}
write this it works
it happens because json stores files as dictionary
and also use this line in beg command
with open("bank.json", 'r') as f:
users = json.dump(users, f)
CHANGE R(READ MODE) TO W(WRITE MODE)
SO THAT IS STORES HOW MUCH COINS YOU HAVE

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I made using Repl.it (the command is $coins add #):

```
from replit import db
if message.content.startswith('$coins add'):
    db['coinmsg']=message.content
message=db['coinmsg']
amount = message.replace('$coins add ','')
db["amount"] = int(amount)
db["coins"]=db["coins"]+db["amount"]
addtobank=str(db["amount"]) + ' coins were added to the bank' 
    await message.channel.send(addtobank)
```

Answer (score -1):

open the json file and add the brace or curly brackets ({}) -_-